# PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass

Tags: json, php

Происходит ошибка:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/p21522/public_html/vk2/src/Vkontakte.php on line 417
```

417 строка скрипта:

```
'attachments' => "{$response[0]->id}", // uploaded image is passed as attachment
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use the second parameter of json_decode to make it return an array:
>
> $result = json_decode($data, true);

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815520/cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array

Примечание: Первый результат поиска в Google описывает подобную ошибку, связанную с использованием функции json_decode. По приведённому фрагменту кода сложно сделать выводы о данной ошибке.

Comment: @bitrixoid, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: @bitrixoid, вообще конечно подход правильный, но он все равно упадет:

    {$response[0]->id}

В этом случае загасится уже `->id`, потому что там будет массив. Вообще проблемы, похоже, в библиотеке, и ничего тут толком не сделать.